# Reopen an already running application(.exe) using java

Tags: java

I have a java program that opens up a .exe file. What i want to do is,

1)Run the .exe file when the java program is executed - Runs perfectly

2) When running the same code again, I want to reopen the previously executed exe.I dont want the .exe file to execute again.

**EDIT:**
Is there a way to do the above? My only concern is the 2nd question. I have made the 1st question to work

Comment: what do you mean by `reopen`

Comment: Unless you've setup some interprocess comms, I don't think you can "re-attach" to a running process through pure Java.  It "might" be possible to do it using a JNI/JNA solution, but you'd have to investigate each OS individually

Comment: @FastSnail That's the requirement of the client.. If the exe is already running and if the user executes the java app again.. the exe must not be executed again. Instead it should be maximized or something like that

Comment: @MadProgrammer So you mean to say there is no pure java for it? :'(

Comment: @Chaze None that I'm aware of

Comment: @MadProgrammer Any way to just maximize the window of the exe file?

Comment: @Chaze Not with pure Java

Comment: @FastSnail reopen in the sense, maximizing it, bringing it to the foreground.. anything.. i just want to make the user see the exe window again.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh ok :( anyways thanks for the replies :)

Comment: One-instance windows app (with resolving already running instance & show) is broad published on codeproject. This has nothing to do with Java, more to this "windows EXE"

Comment: Looking at above comments you can execute a command to get current running task in window. By using this you can get the list of all running process and their name.. but I'm not sure how to reopen that process again. I hope this will help you

Comment: @Luffy I have achieved that.. The only challenge i am facing is to show the user, the exe window again..

Comment: @Chaze Oh that's great Congrats :). Will you please post how your answer. So that If anyone is having same problem then they can get help from your answer.

Comment: @Luffy I have posted my code as u requested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

On the request of Luffy. This is the code that i had used to get the list of running process and check whether a particular exe is running or not. Hope it helps for others.

```
 try 
    {
        String line;
        String pidInfo = "";
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic.exe");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
        oStream .write("process where name='test.exe'");
        oStream .flush();
        oStream .close();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            pidInfo+=line;
        }
        input.close();

        if(pidInfo.contains("test.exe"))
        {
            System.out.println("exe already running");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("exe not running");
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ToTestEXE\\test.exe"});
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer..  +1.

Comment: @Luffy Thanks you too :) My 1st ever questions and these many responses.. Never knew i would get 21 reputations for just one simple question :D Thank you everyone :)

Comment: And waking-up (taking to visible) ?

Comment: @JacekCz That part i was not able to do it..That's what i said before i answered my own question  _"This is the code that i had used to get the list of running process and check whether a particular exe is running or not."_

Comment: This "classic" program ("windows EXE") is Yours, or customer have source?

Comment: @JacekCz u mean the test.exe?